# Mutiple Threading in Servlets & JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets

How JSP and Servlets differ on the concept of Multiple Threading? OR Is the concept of Multiple Threading even existing in both/any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSPs will be compiled to Servlets when run in a container. 
Both Servlet and JSPs will be accessed by multiple threads while requests are being handled.